# Notification 'Message Sent' for write command

Tags: shell-script, write

I need to use the `write` command to send someone a message. Using a shell script if the message is sent successfully I want to have a 'Message sent!' notification pop up and if possible, end the shell script after that.

I pretty much need `write` to only have 1 input (not when executing the script), and then the script to continue. I can't find anything useful on this. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how to use this site. To get to your question, could you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/557048/edit) your post to include more details. What have you tried so far and what is not working? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

user=$1

read -rp "Enter your message for ${user}: " message

write "$user" <<EOF 2>/dev/null
$message
EOF

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' 'Message sent!'
fi
```

usage:

```
$ ./script.sh jesse_b
```

Comment: I don't want to type the message when executing it.. Is there a way to have do stuff that I want it to do and then prompt a write to type a message and then end it? Kind of like the following but the notification is shown in the next line
.
.
.
Enter your message: (I type here the message)
Message Sent!

Comment: +1 Jesse_b, you edited the body of your script to conform to OP's (belated) comment on when exactly to introduce the message, but you forgot to modify your Usage line....

Comment: It came up with this error: ./task4.sh: line 37: warning: here-document at line 25 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./task4.sh: line 38: syntax error: unexpected end of file...
I had this error with the previous code too and I couldn't find what's wrong with it.. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Still didn't work.. I think it has something to do with this part... write "$user" <<EOF 2>/dev/null
$message
EOF

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΚόντης: "Didn't work" is not useful information.  What about it do you think is wrong?

Comment: probably something to do with "<<EOF 2>/dev/null $message EOF".. I dont completely understand that part so I'm not sure I know exactly what it's supposed to do with each word.. The error is still the same as before.. Do you want me to post the full script? I have tested the script without the part that is in the quotes above and it works if I do ctrl+d after i type the message

Comment: What do you mean "post the full script"?  If you are using a script other than the one I provided in my answer then you aren't using my solution.

Comment: I'm using that code as a part of the script.. Do you want me to post the rest? It just has a bunch of checks.. It's nothing really important..

Comment: So the EOF needed to be at the beggining of the line... I don't know why it took me so long.. Thanks for the help and sorry that I wasted your time a bit!